# Dynamically package css & js for templates

Tags: javascript, css, freemarker, templating-engine

Sitrep:

- My pages are built on free marker templates. The currently include the css and js needed for it in the template file itself. But this results in quite a few duplicates.

What I want to do :

- I want to be able to do a free marker analogue of the C++ #include. Basically a template mentions the js and css it needs and it gets picked from a central place when the template is rendering.

Are there any preprocessors for this? Are there any approaches to this better than the #include?

Comment: There's an `#include` directive: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html

Comment: Yup. That includes other free marker files. That page makes no mention of external style sheets.

Comment: You can put the entire content of your external css file into a template. You can then include it in the main template. Why won't that work for you?

Comment: That would work. But it just seems like a hack. Write a .ftl file with no free marker code at all

Comment: May be showing an example of your code, would give us some idea about what is needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly insert the content of that CSS or JS into your HTML output then there's nothing wrong with `#include`-ing it. FreeMarker doesn't care what kind of file is that: the extension can remain `.css` or `.js`, and you can use `<#include ... parse=false>` to prevent accidental interpretation as FTL (though certainly you don't have `${...}`-s etc. in a `.js` or `.css`).

Comment: So it's fine/acceptable to have an ftl file with no ftl code?

Comment: Yes, especially as you are using it as a reusable piece of other templates. Reusing common fragments is the main point of `#include` and macros. Note that the included file doesn't have to be `.ftl`.